# Specify date format for Python argparse input arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have a Python script that requires some command line inputs and I am using `argparse` for parsing them. I found the documentation a bit confusing and couldn't find a way to check for a format in the input parameters. What I mean by checking format is explained with this example script:

```
parser.add_argument('-s', "--startdate", help="The Start Date - format YYYY-MM-DD ", required=True)
parser.add_argument('-e', "--enddate", help="The End Date format YYYY-MM-DD (Inclusive)", required=True)
parser.add_argument('-a', "--accountid", type=int, help='Account ID for the account for which data is required (Default: 570)')
parser.add_argument('-o', "--outputpath", help='Directory where output needs to be stored (Default: ' + os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

I need to check for option `-s` and `-e` that the input by the user is in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Is there an option in `argparse` that I do not know of which accomplishes this?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type):

> The `type` keyword argument of `add_argument()` allows any necessary type-checking and type conversions to be performed ... The argument to `type` can be any callable that accepts a single string.

You could do something like:

```
import argparse
import datetime


def valid_date(s: str) -> datetime.datetime:
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except ValueError:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"not a valid date: {s!r}")
```

Then use that as `type`:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "-s", 
    "--startdate", 
    help="The Start Date - format YYYY-MM-DD", 
    required=True, 
    type=valid_date
)
```

If the user supplies an invalid value, the feedback will look like:

```
error: argument -s/--startdate: not a valid date: 'foo'
```

Comment: About the other question that you edited out can you point me to the documentation (if any) for that?

Comment: Does `valid_date()` assume the given argument is a string?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro yes, but that's what the API defines; *"takes a single string argument"* per the quote from the docs.

Comment: I get `NameError: name 's' is not defined` with this code.

Comment: @GeorgPfolz `s` is defined in the parameter list for `valid_date`, so that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 84):

Just to add on to the answer above, you can use a lambda function if you want to keep it to a one-liner. For example:

```
parser.add_argument('--date', type=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

If the user supplies an invalid value, the feedback will look like:

```
error: argument -e/--enddate: invalid <lambda> value: 'foo'
```

Comment: This is a nice trick, although if you pass something invalid, the error message will just be `invalid <lambda> value`

Answer (score 73):

In Python 3.7 you can use the standard `.fromisoformat` class method instead of reinventing the wheel for ISO-8601 compliant dates, e.g.:

```py
import datetime

parser.add_argument('-s', "--startdate",
    help="The Start Date - format YYYY-MM-DD",
    required=True,
    type=datetime.date.fromisoformat)
parser.add_argument('-e', "--enddate",
    help="The End Date format YYYY-MM-DD (Inclusive)",
    required=True,
    type=datetime.date.fromisoformat)
```

If the user supplies an invalid valid, the feedback will look like:

```
error: argument -e/--enddate: invalid fromisoformat value: 'foo'
```

Comment: In addition, [`dateutil`'s](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil) ISO parser takes a number of additional fmts that are still ISO 8601-2004 compliant.  You can use `import dateutil.parser` --> `type=dateutil.parser.isoparse` or `type=dateutil.parser.parse`

Comment: @BradSolomon Indeed a good suggestion (hence my +1), but `dateutil` is a third-party package. One would have to judge its benefits against the (small) hassle of installing it extra. YMMV.

Comment: Very elegant solution!