# Why can you assign functions to type, const and default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to understand why this code works. Why can you give `type`, `const` and `default` a built-in function?

```
def printList(i):
    print("Integer:", i)
    return(i)

def getParser():
    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("integers", type=printList, nargs="+")
    parser.add_argument("--sum", dest="accumulate", const=sum, default=max, nargs="?")
    return(parser)


args = getParser().parse_args(["2", "3", "9", "5"])
print(args.integers)
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

Output:

```
>>> Integer: 2
>>> Integer: 3
>>> Integer: 9
>>> Integer: 5
>>> ['2', '3', '9', '5'] 
>>> 9
```

I want to understand why it is working.

**Edit:**

You misunderstood me.

For example "type" I would expect to see "type=int", because you want only to allow Integers. So you give "type" something. 
But in my example "type" gives something to the "printList" functions, so that it can print it. 
Or for example "default". I would expect to give some value, liken an int or str. I give something to "default". But in my example I give the build-in function "max". Why does "max" get a list?
Why is that working? That is what I want to know.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you be able to? What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: Consider `default=max` - it says that if the user doesn't supply a parameter, use the `max` function. Its a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: it's allowed because it's useful, as you can see in your own example  :)  functions are just values, so they'd have to go out of their way to _not_ allow it, and there's no reason to do so

Comment: You misunderstood me.

For example "type" I would expect to see "type=int", because you want only to allow Integers. So you give "type" something. But in my example "type" gives something to the "printList" functions, so that it can print it. Or for example "default". I would expect to give some value, liken an int or str. I give something to "default". But in my example I give the build-in function "max". Why does "max" get a list? Why is that working? That is what I want to know.

Comment: @OliverHD You don't have to write that on *everything*, you know...

Answer (score 1):

```
parser.add_argument("--sum", dest="accumulate", const=sum, default=max, nargs="?")
```

is, assuming you don't supply an argument with `'--sum'`, a *little* bit like:

```
args.accumulate = sum if '--sum' in arg_list else max
                               # ^ it also needs to be in the right place!
```

Per [the docs for `nargs='?'`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and
>   produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the
>   value from default will be produced. Note that for optional arguments,
>   there is an additional case - the option string is present but not
>   followed by a command-line argument. In this case the value from const
>   will be produced.

Functions are first-class objects in Python, and can be passed around like any other object, so there's no reason they can't be used for `const` and `default`.

---

Note that if you actually *did* supply an argument with `'--sum'`, `args.accumulate` would be that value instead:

```
>>> args = getParser().parse_args(["1", "--sum", "this one"])
('Integer:', '1')
>>> args.accumulate
'this one'
```

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me.

For example "type" I would expect to see "type=int", because you want only to allow Integers. So you give "type" something. But in my example "type" gives something to the "printList" functions, so that it can print it. Or for example "default". I would expect to give some value, liken an int or str. I give something to "default". But in my example I give the build-in function "max". Why does "max" get a list? Why is that working? That is what I want to know.

Comment: @OliverHD `default` **is** *"some value"*, only it's a function object instead of e.g. an integer object. Again, **functions are first-class objects**. `max` gets a list because **you explicitly pass it one**: `args.accumulate(args.integers)`. And `type` can be any callable that returns a value or raises an error; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25470943/3001761 for another use.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

`argparse` expects `type` to be a callable (with limited provision for a string).

`argparse` allows `const` and `default`  to be almost anything.  It doesn't do anything with them except assign them to an attribute (or pass them to your `type` callable).

Long answer:

From the internal documentation, for `class Action`:

> - type -- A callable that accepts a single string argument, and
>             returns the converted value.  The standard Python types str, int,
>             float, and complex are useful examples of such callables.  If None,
>             str is used.
> - default -- The value to be produced if the option is not specified.
> - const -- The value to be produced if the option is specified and the
>             option uses an action that takes no values.

`parse.add_argument` creates an `Action`, using the `action` parameter to specify the subclass.  You can look at this object interactively or with:

```
a = parser.add_argument(....)
print(repr(a))
```

Parameters like `type`, `nargs`, `default` are stored as attributes of this object.

At some depth in the `parse_args` action, `parser._get_values()` ends up calling `parser._get_value` on each string that is allocated to a particular action.

```
def _get_value(self, action, arg_string):
    type_func = self._registry_get('type', action.type, action.type)
    if not callable(type_func):
        msg = _('%r is not callable')
        raise ArgumentError(action, msg % type_func)

    # convert the value to the appropriate type
    try:
        result = type_func(arg_string)
```

This looks in a dictionary (`parser._registries`) to see if `action.type` has been defined (as a string).  If not, it assumes `action.type` is itself a function. The `type` is used in the `result = type_func(arg_string)` line.

As a default `None` is the only registered `type`

```
def identity(string):
   return string
```

`argparse.FileType` is a factory that creates a `type` function, one that can open a file (i.e. take a file name and return an open file).

`int`, `float` are builtin Python functions that take a string and return a value, or raise an error if there is a problem.  These specify the function that is called to convert the string.  They do not, directly, specify that the string must represent an integer or float.   Users sometimes mistakenly use `boolean` in the same way.

The `action` parameter is looked up in the `_registries`.  All of the default action classes have an entry, hence we use values like `store`, `store_true`, and `append`.  But we can also specify a custom Action class.

As for `default`, early in the `parse_args` stack, this line is executed for each action (defined argument):

```
setattr(namespace, action.dest, action.default)
```

This makes not assumptions about the nature of `action.default`.  It could be `None`, a string, a number, a list, a function, or any Python object.

Near the end of `parse_args`, it may pass `action.default` through the `type` function.  It does this only if `default` is a string.

```
 setattr(namespace, action.dest, self._get_value(action, action.default))
```

Look at your `args`.  It probably looks like:

```
Namespace(integers=['2', '3', '9', '5'], accumulate=max)
```

Since you did not specify a `--sum` option, the default value is placed in the namespace without change or checking.  If you had specified `--sum`, but without an argument, then `accumulate=sum` (the `const` parameter) would be in the name space.  But `--sum some_other_function` would have created `accumulate="some_other_function"`.

Your chosen `type` function has the side effect of printing its input, but it returns the string unchanged, hence you see strings in the `integers` list.

When you execute

```
args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

It is the same as

```
max(["2", "3", "9", "5"])
```

which returns `"9"` - the string, not the number.

```
sum(["2", "3", "9", "5"])
```

raise an error.  The misnamed `printList` only prints a string, not a list, and does not convert its values to integers.

Sorry to be long winded, but you did ask what is going on.  In short, `argparse` is written to give the user a lot of power, but it also tries to handle many common cases in a simple default manner.

Answer (score 0):

Because functions are first-class objects in Python. They can be bound, accessed, and moved around just like any other type.

```
>>> foo = max
>>> foo(2, 3, 1)
3
```