# While using Python's add_argument in argparse, how can I throw an exception if a particular deprecated flag is called?

Tags: python, parsing, exception, action, argparse

Basically imagine that I have argparser that has multiple arguments.
I have a particular function definition that looks like this:

```
    def add_to_parser(self, parser):
        group = parser.add_argument_group('')
        group.add_argument( '--deprecateThis', action='throw exception', help='Stop using this. this is deprecated')
```

Whether I can try and create that action to throw an exception and stop the code or if I can wrap it to check for the `deprecateThis` flag and then throw an exception, I'd like to know how to do it and which is best!  Thanks.

Comment: You could provide a `type` function that throws an error if anything is supplied to it. Or yes, just check after the parsing if there's anything in that argument.

Comment: but what if I want to have "action=throwexception" or something?  Where would I be providing the type function to do so?  Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: No, there are [predefined actions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action). Demo of using `type`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25470943/3001761

Comment: That works!  Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe :) If you wanna answer it, i'll give you the check!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with:

You can register custom actions for your arguments, I registered one to print out a deprecation warning and remove the item from the resulting namespace:

```
class DeprecateAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.call_count = 0
        if 'help' in kwargs:
            kwargs['help'] = f'[DEPRECATED] {kwargs["help"]}'
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if self.call_count == 0:
            sys.stderr.write(f"The option `{option_string}` is deprecated. It will be ignored.\n")
            sys.stderr.write(self.help + '\n')
            delattr(namespace, self.dest)
        self.call_count += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_parser = ArgumentParser('this is the description')
    my_parser.register('action', 'ignore', DeprecateAction)
    my_parser.add_argument(
        '-f', '--foo', 
        help="This argument is deprecated", 
        action='ignore')

    args = my_parser.parse_args()
    # print(args.foo)  # <- would throw an exception
```

Answer (score 0):

During a project’s lifetime, some arguments may need to be removed from the command line. Before removing them, you should inform your users that the arguments are deprecated and will be removed. So your program should not stop, but instead it should show a warning.

Starting from python 3.13, you can use a parameter `deprecated` in methods `add_argument()` and `add_parser()`, which allows to deprecate command-line options, positional arguments and subcommands.

In this case, all you need to do is:

```
group.add_argument( '--deprecateThis', deprecated=True)
```